# How generation help garbage collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I've read few articles about how garbage collection works and still don't understand how using generations helps? As I understood the main idea is that we start collection from the youngest generation and move to older generations. But why the authors of this idea decided that starting from the youngest generation is the most efficient way?

Comment: There are many short-lived objects; short lived objects are more handed around (actively used), and need more treatment. Consider short lived inner loop objects. Do a research elsewhere in the web. A nice answer would be _article_ length.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the application. I mean I can write application in which there will be no short lived objects at all. What if so?

Comment: (Compare it with an extra sorting key/index in a database: no short lived object: fast done. Running the other way around, starting with an old generation: most times inspecting for nothing. And dealing with short lived objects is crucial.)

Comment: If you ever write `for (String s : myStringList)` in a short loop, then a short lived `Iterator` gets created. The same if you ever call a varargs method. Putting something in a `HashMap` creates an `Entry`, chances are the map gets discarded or the entry removed soon. You can write an application avoiding it all, but it'd be a real mess.

Answer (score 3):

The older the generation, means object has been used quite a many times, and possibly will need again.
Removing recently created object makes no sense, May be its temporary(scope : local) object.

Comment: Possible will need again? Who decides it?

Comment: Statistics, Lets say you need one object obj, All over in the application, Application is running, For first three times GC ran, obj was in use, it has generation 3 now, Next time when GC will run even if obj is not in use. High chance that it will be needing again. Why take risk of loading it again when next time app needs it. Rather keep it. and remove least used.

Comment: @nikhilr57 Your last two sentences are wrong. An object can't be removed if there's any change of needing it again. It should read: **Why to waste time with determining if an old object can be removed. Rather try the new ones where the chances are higher.**

Comment: @AndreyYaskulsky if there's still a reference to an object, it could be 'need[ed] again' - it's a simple as that.  The object graph is walked from the GC roots, any object in that graph is NOT garbage, everything else is.

Answer (score 2):

The authors start with the youngest generation first simply because that's what gets filled up first after your application starts, however in reality which generation is being swept and when is non-deterministic as your application runs.

The important points with generational GC are:

- the young generation uses a copying collector which is copying objects to a space that it considers to be empty (the unused survivor spaces) from eden and the current survivor space and is therefore fast and the GC pause is minimal.
- add to this fact that most objects die young and therefore the pause required to copy a small number of surviving objects from the eden and the current surviver space is small as only objects with *live* references are copied, after which eden and the previous survivor space can be wiped.
- after being copied several times objects are copied to the tenured (old) generation; Eventually the tenured generation will fill up, however, this time there's not a clean space to copy the objects to, so the garbage collector has to sweap and compact within the generation, which is slow (when compared to the copy performed in eden and the survivor space) meaning a longer pause.
- the good news, based on the most objects die young heuristic is, major GCs happen much less frequently than minor keeping GC pauses to a minimum over the lifetime of an application.
- there's also a benefit that all new objects are allocated on the top of the heap, meaning there's mininal instructions required to do so, with defragmentation occurring naturally as part of the copy process.

Both these pages, [Oracle Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) and [Useful JVM Flags – Part 5 (Young Generation Garbage Collection)](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/08/useful-jvm-flags-part-5-young-generation-garbage-collection/), describe this.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [one](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073905/build-ci-sdlc/pick-up-performance-with-generational-garbage-collection.html).

Using different generations, makes the allocation of objects easy and fast as MOST of the allocations are done in a single region of Heap - Eden. Based on the observation that most objects die young from Weak Generational Hypothesis, collections in Young generation have more garbage which will reclaim more memory and its relatively small compared to the heap which means that time taken to scan the objects is also less. Thats why Young generation GCs are fast.

For more details on GC and generations, you can refer to [this](http://learnerslog.com/2014/07/garbage-collection-in-java/)